# POSIX conformance: NetBSD 5.1 <sys/time.h> gettimeofday declaration

Tags: posix, netbsd

I'm compiling some code which requests POSIX 1003.1 1993 conformance via `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=2`.

The code includes the header `<sys/time.h>` and wants to call `gettimeofday`, but on NetBSD 5.1 there is a compiler warning about that function not being declared.

Looking into NetBSD's header, we see that the declaration of `gettimeofday` is wrapped with a test for `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` being at least `200112`.

Was `gettimeofday` really only introduced to POSIX in 2001? That hardly seems right. In 1993, there was already `clock_gettime` with nanoseconds and different clock types, and `getttimeofday` is ancient 4.2 BSD stuff.

In the GNU C library's `<sys/time.h>`, `gettimeofday` is not wrapped by anything at all.

Which is is right: NetBSD header, or my code relying on `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=2` to reveal the declaration of `gettimeofday` (and glibc, for providing it unconditionally)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/gettimeofday.html does indeed say it was added in 2001.

Comment: I don't see where it says that. But aha, I didn't see this before. It mentions Issue 4, Version 2. That's 1997.

Comment: Look here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/gettimeofday.html    It was already in the Single Unix Spec in 1997.

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom, the "SEE ALSO" section references the POSIX version where it was added.  (Not the *current* version, which for that particular reference is 2004.)

Comment: Also note that SUS and POSIX were not quite the same thing back then; SUS was The Open Group's original attempt at reconciling SVID and OSF/1 behavior, as distinct from ANSI's (POSIX) or X/Open's.  They have since been merged into a single standard.

Comment: Looks like it may be a Unix95 thing that didn't in fact get into POSIX 1003 until 2001.

Comment: Thanks for that; I'm staying conservative and going with `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE` rather than requesting newer POSIX. This gets me the `gettimeofday` declaration.